# How can you create an 'if' statement using an integer input and use an equation to generate the answer?

Tags: python, if-statement, integer, user-input, equation

My assignment is as follows:

This week we will implement “if statements” in a program by modifying our program from week 2. In week 2, we calculated the total cost of fiber cable installation by multiplying the number of feet by $.87. This week, we will evaluate a bulk discount. Modify your week 2 program so that if the user purchases more than 100 feet, they are charged $.80 per foot. If the user purchases more than 250 feet, they will be charged $.70 per foot. If they purchase more than 500 feet, they will be charged $.50 per foot.
Steps:
Display a welcome message for your program.
Get the company name from the user.
Get the number of feet of fiber optic to be installed from the user.
Evaluate the total cost based on the number of feet requested.
Display the calculated information including the number of feet requested and the company name.

I entered:

```
print ("Welcome to Fiber Optic Solutions")
message=input ("Please state the name of your company: ")
print (f"Thank you {message},")
print ("Our cost per foot of fiber optic cable is .87.")
print ("If you purchase more than 100ft, your price is .80")
print ("If you purchase more than 250ft, your price is .70")
feet=input ("Please state how many feet of cable you require: ")
costperfoot= (.87)
costperfoot2= (.80)
costperfoot3= (.70)
print(feet)
if (feet) >= 100:
print (f"You qualify for discount")
```

I tested each line on python as I went.  When I got here python responded with:

```
  if (feet) >= 100:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: `feet` is a `str` and can't be compared with an `int`

Comment: `input()` returns a string.  You need to convert `feet` to a numeric value by calling `int()` (or `float()` if whole numbers are not required), like this: `feet=int(input ("..."))`

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have also mentioned, you are trying to compare different types. In your case an int and a str. Calling `feet = int(feet)` would make the value an integer and reassign it back to the variable. Depending on the intention, you can keep asking for a valid number until one is given by the user.

```
...
while True:
    #  Get input from user. (type str)
    feet = input("Enter value...")
    try:
        #  Try to convert provided value to an integer.
        #  If the provided value is not a number, raises TypeError.
        feet = int(feet)  # or float(feet) for decimal values.
        #  No exception is raised, meaning value is a valid number.
        break
    except TypeError:
        #  Value wasnt a number so we keep asking.
        continue
...
```